# index.php server routing "if" codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

in codeigniter on my index.php I would like to know what is the best way to check if the database has connection. Because I use both MySQL and MySQLI

And if has connection then able to view website/server other wise through error or if file exist go to chosen sub-directory.

I am not sure on how to set it up on index.php in codeigniter.

Not working

```
if ($db_obj->conn_id === false) { 
// redirects to location if file exists
if(file_exists(header('Location: '.rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/').'/install/index.php/'))) {
} else {
echo "Sorry No Database Connection";
} else {

// view website/server?
header('Location: '.rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($db_obj->conn_id === false) {
```

The above is the code to see if you have a database connection.

You can then use this to route to the correct page.

However I would ask - WHY would you build a database dependant system and have a none database back-up - also why use mysql AND mysqli - this is a terribad idea and you shouldn't be using mysql anymore as it is deprecated!

Comment: Just because I am making a module that allows people that do not have much php experience to be able to enter database via front end form. And connects it and up loads a sql file but very basic just to get them started. I have got most of it done just stuck on that.

Comment: Fair enough - good luck with it! Glad to see you are building in HMVC and using modules!

Comment: Yes I am. I tired this not work. Not sure what done wrong.
if ($db_obj->conn_id === false) { 
// redirects to location if file exists
if(file_exists(header('Location: '.rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/').'/install/index.php/'))) {
} else {
echo "Sorry No Database Connection";
} else {
header('Location: '.rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
exit;
}

Comment: I have edited my code in main topic to show your db_obj but not working way I am after.

Comment: You are missing a `}` to close off the first if statement

Comment: tried it but now just make page unable to load. "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: use the codeigniter built in URL redirects as part of the URL helper class - also where are you trying to do this again? You said in the index.php file - but if you are building a module you shouldn't be touching this file at all!

Comment: I have another codeigniter install in a sub-directory with its on app and index.php The I am trying to get redirected to if codeigniter main app does not have database connection.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with this -> have you considered making a library for this instead -> I have never attempted to run two codeigniter installs together so don't know how that affects your URL re-writes, routing etc.